# How can I use the index in my array list and convert to int?

Tags: java, arrays

I am struggling using the indexes of the elements in my array and convert it to int.

I can't find something useful on google.

For example, I have a string array
A [] = {apple, banana, cat}

and then I want the indexes of each element to be an integer like this  and is stored in an int array
a [] = {0, 1, 2}

Comment: It seems a bit strange to me why you would want to store the contiguous integers from 0 to n in an array of length n. an `int` does the same job.

Comment: Well, the bigger picture of this is that I have a string array and I cannot count the inversion, if it is in a string array. So, I would rather convert the indexes of the elements and store it into in an int array. And it will be possible for me to count the inversion

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IntStream.range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-):

```
int[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, array.length).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO Stefaney.

You can do like this:

```
int[] indexes = new int[array.length];
Arrays.setAll(indexes, i -> i);
```

Comment: That's impressive! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a `for` loop:

```
int[] indexes = new int[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    indexes[i] = i;
}
```

However, I think @iota's is a more elegant answer, using `IntStream`.